# Change map settings by element id

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Have code:

```
jQuery(function() {
  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mymap'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(12, 34),
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
});
```

needs without change this code change map type.

```
jQuery(function() {
  var map = ???
  map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the map after your function ends as it is no longer accessible.

The only way to do it is to give it a name so you can access it (which can only be done by changing the code that can't be changed):

```
var map = null;
jQuery(function() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mymap'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(12, 34),
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
});
```

Your title says "by element id", you can't modify a javascript object using HTML ids.